# Page getting cached in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, ajax, random

I am trying to display random products on the homepage. but my page is getting cached and on refresh, same products are displayed. I used AJAX post request also but did not work. Can anybody say how can I avoid my page getting cached?

Read many articles, tried every possible way, but did not work.
Here is my ajax code

```
<script>
    require([
        'jquery'
    ], function($){
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/homepage/ajax/loadcategory",
        type: "POST",
        data: "",
        success: function (res) {
            if(res.indexOf("find products matching the selection") > -1){
             alert("Hello world.......");
            return;
            }
         alert("Hello world");
            var result = jQuery('.product-item-info', res).html();
            jQuery(".product-item").show();
            jQuery(".randomProd .product-item .product-item-info").html(result);
        }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you add your Ajax code?

Comment: @ToanTam Edited my question

Comment: try this one before adding $('.randomProd .product-item .product-item-info').empty();

Comment: @AmritPalSingh Sorry,did not work

Comment: Load your products by creating a block and in the xml, make that block cachable false

Comment: @MGento Did that.still not working

Comment: Can you check your ajax response to make sure you are getting new data and not the same data every time?